# how to fire window service to update local database when remote database table being updated?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, windows-services, c#-3.0

Below problem I searched in "Stack Overflow" but don't get relevant information...

I am using .Net(C#) and SqlServer2008. My problem is below:

1. I have a remote Database by name 'RemoteDB' that have a table by name 'UserTBL' Table
2. I have a loca Database by name 'LocalDB' that have a table by name 'UserTBL' Table with same structure as in remote database table
3. I have a window service for updating local databse Table 'UserTBL' when Remote Table 'UserTBL' is updated ie. I have to reflect same changes in local table 'UserTBL' that were made in remote table.
4. window service should be executed only when remote table gets updated.

I am trying to resolve above problem but unable to resolve.

Please guide me how to start to do it...If you will place Code Samples or link it will be very helpful for me...

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152516/c-sql-database-listener-help-needed

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=VS.80).aspx